# If I have two versions of cmake installed, how should I make pip use one of them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, pip

I have cmake-3.4 installed in /usr/local/doc/cmake-3.4

But pip 21.0 requires cmake>=3.6 (version)

I don't have administrative permissions to install cmake-3.6 in /usr/local/doc/

So I installed the cmake 3.6 in my home directory.

But even now, while installing a package using pip, it uses cmake 3.4

How can I make the pip use cmake 3.6 installed in my home direcotry?

Comment: What are you doing? You've skipped vital information which would explain why `pip` depends on `cmake`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `cmake-3.4` isn't installed in `/usr/local/doc/`. There you'll only find the documentation. Change your `PATH` variable and add the path to `cmake-3.6` before the path to `cmake-3.4`. You can find out the path to `cmake-3.4` with `which cmake`.